# How can I set the maxDate for mobiscroll?

Tags: javascript, maxdate, mobiscroll

I´m wondering how I could set the max date on the mobiscroll. I know that i should use the maxDate option but I cannot find how the string should be formatted anywhere. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with mobiscroll, but if I understood correctly, its [documentation](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/) says that *maxDate* accepts the `Date` global object. So, actually, the format can be anything accepted by the standard JavaScript `Date`:

Here's a documentation for `Date` from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

And some examples of use quoted from it:

```
new Date("December 17, 1995 03:24:00");
new Date(1995,11,17);
new Date(1995,11,17,3,24,0);
```

Comment: picker.mobiscroll().date(  
            {
                minDate: new Date('2010,1,1'),
                maxDate: new Date('2030,1,1')
            });