# HTML Input Date Type Only Showing Old Years on Android Web App

Tags: android, html, date, input

I've got a hybrid Android app with an HTML input:

```
<input type="date" id="expDate" name="expDate" placeholder="Select a date"/>
```

When I click on the input I only get years 2015 and below as per:

[image]

When I do the exact same thing in a Hybrid iOS app I get the years going out for decades.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you tried adding max property to date in your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise it but we are using MobiScroll to do this and they have their own max and min dates you need to apply. See [How can I set the maxDate for mobiscroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947396/how-can-i-set-the-maxdate-for-mobiscroll) for the answer but here is my implementation:

```
        picker.mobiscroll().date(  
        {
            theme: 'android-holo',
            display: 'bottom',
            mode: 'scroller',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            minDate: new Date('2010,1,1'),
            maxDate: new Date('2030,1,1')
        });
```

Thanks to Akhil for pointng me in the right direction.

We only use this for Android and not iOS.